# Making a chained list out of a TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, linked-list, treeview

I have a `TreeView` composed of many `Nodes` on several levels.
Depending on the level, the nodes contain a `Tag` of the object they represent.

```
node_lvl_1.1:
|    node_lvl_2.1:
|    |    node_lvl_3.1
|    |    node_lvl_3.2
|    node_lvl_2.2:
|    |    node_lvl_3.1
|    |    node_lvl_3.2
...
```

(the reality is of course more complex)

I'm trying to set an ID (just like the after the `.`) to each of the objects. 
I'm also trying to create some kind of chained list - as in:
`Obj lvl1` contains a list of all `Obj lvl2` which also contain a list of all `Obj lvl3` ...

I've used these two functions to give each node the object which corresponds to it.

```
    public static void Define(TreeNode mainNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode subNode in mainNode.Nodes)
        {
            if(subNode.Nodes.Count != 0)
            {
                Define(subNode);
            }
            else
            {
                subNode.ToolTipText = "Local";
            }
            DefineHierarchy(subNode);
        }
    }

    public static void DefineHierarchy(TreeNode tn)
    {
        switch (tn.ToolTipText)
        {
            case "0":
                tn.Tag = new Entite(tn.Text);
                break;
            case "1":
                tn.Tag = new Secteur(tn.Text);
                break;
            case "2":
                tn.Tag = new SousSecteur(tn.Text);
                break;
            case "3":
                tn.Tag = new Zone(tn.Text);
                break;
            case "Local":
                tn.Tag = new Local(tn.Text);
                break;
            default:
                tn.Tag = "between Zone and Local";
                break;
        }
        tn.ToolTipText = tn.Tag.ToString();
    }
```

I hope I'm clear enough :/ and thanks for any help!

Comment: the fact that you are using different classes for each level (entité, secteur, ...), will add complexity. do they all inherit from the same base class so you could generalize? what is your expected output?

Comment: None of them inherit from anything, they are just basic simple classes containg an ID (always at 0 atm - except for entité) a name and a list of lower level elements. They will be more detailed later.

Comment: The desired output is an excel sheet containing these columns: Entité_ID // Entité_Name // Secteur_ID // Secteur_Name ... when all the data will be gathered, there will be more than 100 columns

Comment: Actually, the only reason i'm posting this question here, is because I thought it would be the easiest way to convert a tree view to an excel sheet of the same kind

Comment: @dlatikay if you have any proposition of a better way to achieve the ultimate goal, i'll gladly follow any advice